# NextJS 13 Pages router `notFound` in getServerSideProps not redirecting to custom 404 page

Tags: next.js

NextJS is loading the default 404 page, despite `pages/404.tsx` existing and working (manual navigation shows it). This is relatively recent. We experience it in both local development and deployed on Vercel. `"next": "^13.1.5"`

A failing example from our code:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<ICreatorResponse, ICreatorUrl> = async ({ params, req }) => {
    return {
        notFound: true,
    };
};
```